# Is it possible to debug x64 assembly on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, debugging, assembly

I would like to be able to write and debug x64 assembly on my Mac with Sierra 10.12.4. One would think this would not be a particularly difficult or obscure desire, but despite many hours of effort and a lot of searching online I have not succeeded and I haven't found anyone else who has either.

I would prefer to use the NASM assembler, but will use GAS or anything with Intel syntax if I have to. (By the way, note that both gdb and lldb work fine with C files compiled with gcc.)

Here's my situation and what I've tried:

**NASM doesn't work**

I can assemble and link a file and verify it works.

```
$ nasm -f macho64 -g -F dwarf hello2.s -o hello2.o
$ gcc hello2.o -o hello2
$ ./hello2
Hello, world!
```

But I can't debug it with gdb (note that I did do all the necessary codesigning nonsense):

```
$ gdb hello2
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0
<snip>
Reading symbols from hello2...done.
(gdb) list
1   section .data
2
3   msg: db "Hello, world!", 0
4
5   section .text
6       global _main
7       extern _puts
8
9   _main:
10      push    rbp
(gdb) break 10
Breakpoint 1 at 0x0: file hello2.s, line 10.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/mike/GoogleDrive/Projects/Sort/hello2
[New Thread 0x1403 of process 38022]
warning: unhandled dyld version (15)
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x0

Command aborted.
```

And I can't debug it with lldb:

```
$ lldb hello2
(lldb) target create "hello2"
Current executable set to 'hello2' (x86_64).
(lldb) b hello2.s:10
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

**GAS doesn't work**

I can assemble, link, and run:

```
$ gcc -g hello.s -o hello
$ ./hello
Hello, world!
```

But I can't debug with gdb:

```
$ gdb hello
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0
<snip>
Reading symbols from hello...Reading symbols from /Users/mike/GoogleDrive/Projects/Sort/hello.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/hello...done.
done.
(gdb) list
1   .intel_syntax
2   .text
3       .globl _main
4
5   _main:
6       push    rbp
7       mov rbp, rsp
8       lea rdi, [rip + _main.S_0]
9       call    _puts
10      mov rax, 0
(gdb) break 6
No line 6 in the current file.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (6) pending.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/mike/GoogleDrive/Projects/Sort/hello
[New Thread 0x1403 of process 38063]
warning: unhandled dyld version (15)
Hello, world!
[Inferior 1 (process 38063) exited normally]
```

(So it just ran and ignored the breakpoint.)

And I can't debug it with lldb:

```
$ lldb hello
(lldb) target create "hello"
Current executable set to 'hello' (x86_64).
(lldb) b hello.s:6
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

**Things I've found online**

[Here](https://stefan.budeanu.com/mac-os-x-sierra-and-ruby-debugging-an-unhappy-marriage/) is a blog post about `gdb` not working on new versions of Mac OS.

There are a couple old related StackOverflow questions, neither of which provide an adequate answer.

There's also [this way to use Xcode](https://metricpanda.com/compiling-nasm-with-xcode-in-a-cpp-project), which miraculously seems to work... but it doesn't actually do what I want. The debugger is not actually aware of my source file; it's just stepping through the instructions and displaying disassembled code or something. Also I don't want to use XCode.

I asked about this on the NASM mailing list a couple months ago and nobody ever responded.

**So...**

So is it currently impossible to do *one of the most basic things a person might want to do with a computer* using a Mac?

If someone has a way to do this, please show me exactly the necessary commands.

Comment: What version of `nasm`? What version of `gdb`, `llvm`?

Comment: I've tried nasm versions 2.13.01 and 2.14rc0, and gdb versions 7.12.1 and 8.0. lldb-370.0.42. Apple llvm version 8.1.0. I get the same results regardless of version. Are you implying you've gotten debugging to work with some version of this software?

Comment: I'm referring to the nasm 2.13 release note: "The macho object format now supports the dwarf debugging format, as required by newer toolchains." but you've indicated you are on the latest. Did you ask on the nasm forum?

Comment: I asked on the nasm mailing list but not the forum...

Comment: I can't answer your question because I've never used GDB on a Mac, but your objection to using Xcode seems a bit unusual. *"The debugger is not actually aware of my source file; it's just stepping through the instructions and displaying disassembled code or something."* You're writing in assembly, bro. The disassembled code looks exactly the same as your source file!

Comment: Not really. For instance, I can't set a breakpoint at a given line. Labels won't be right. Etc.

Comment: OK, I've now posted a question on the nasm forum also.

Comment: @MikeBenfield I will watch the forum for selfish reasons, I've been *roughing* it with `lldb` as well.

Comment: An additional remark: I tried all this on Linux too. There, debugging with GAS and gdb works fine. But NASM and gdb do not. In fact, it turns out NASM hasn't worked with GDB in almost 5 years. See this [1] bug report. I can also find several NASM forum posts with no responses about this issue. I'm not sure it's possible to debug programs assembled with NASM on any platform.

[1] https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392234

Answer (score 5):

Miracle of miracles, it seems I can do this with clang:

```
$ clang -g -c -x assembler hello.s
$ clang hello.o -o hello
$ ./hello
Hello, world!
$ lldb hello
(lldb) target create "hello"
Current executable set to 'hello' (x86_64).
(lldb) b hello.s:10
Breakpoint 1: where = hello`main + 16, address = 0x0000000100000f7c
(lldb) run
Process 40460 launched: '/Users/mike/GoogleDrive/Projects/Sort/hello' (x86_64)
Hello, world!
Process 40460 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000f7c hello`main at hello.s:10
   7        mov rbp, rsp
   8        lea rdi, [rip + _main.S_0]
   9        call    _puts
-> 10       mov rax, 0
   11       mov rsp, rbp
   12       pop rbp
   13       ret
```

Unfortunately as far as I can tell clang's x64 assembly support is completely undocumented, and I figured out the correct incantations to do this only by experimenting. But it's something, I guess.

Comment: I don't know where to find documentation for the clang assembler, but  Xcode has an option to display the llvm assembly source for a C/C++/ObjC source file (Product->Perform Action->Assemble).  That might allow you to get examples of similar operations that you can crib for your purposes.