# lldb doesn't show code at breakpoint

Tags: macos, nasm, lldb

I'm building an executable from assembly code compiled with NASM. When I load it into LLDB, set a breakpoint at the start symbol, and run to the breakpoint, it halts at the breakpoint but doesn't show me the code. Like this:

```
[work]$ nasm -f macho32 -g test.asm
[work]$ ld test.o
[work]$ lldb a.out
(lldb) target create "a.out"
Current executable set to 'a.out' (i386).
(lldb) breakpoint set -f test.asm -l 78
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`start, address = 0x00001a5e
(lldb) r
Process 40861 launched: '/Users/petebecker/archive/devel/forth/forth/work/a.out' (i386)
Process 40861 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x00001a5e a.out`start at test.asm:78
(lldb)
```

Sometimes, though, when I go through the same build steps, it **does** show the code when it hits the breakpoint. The different behaviors seem to occur pretty randomly.

There must be something that I'm doing wrong, but I can't for the life of me make sense out of this. I'm not one to blame tools, but is there possibly a tool problem here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to debug x64 assembly on Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493487/is-it-possible-to-debug-x64-assembly-on-mac-os)

Comment: @FrankC. - thanks, but that's not it. The key symptom in that question is not being able to set breakpoints. I can set breakpoints, I can step, I can inspect memory, I can disassemble and see symbol names. The problem is that there is no code displayed. The text I show is what happens when it hits the breakpoint. Nothing more, not the usual source lines with the arrow pointing at the current line.

Comment: OK, I retracted the duplicate reference. Curious, no code at all (even if you were to break on _start)?

Comment: @FrankC. -- to be clear, my "thanks" was for pointing to that possible answer; I hope it didn't sound sarcastic. And, no, no code displayed at all. That breakpoint at test.asm:78 is `start` (my ld looks for `start`, not `_start`), and when it hits the breakpoint it tells me it hit it, and doesn't show anything more.

Comment: Not taken any other way! I compile many asm files and link with other objects, from another language, and never had this problem with LLDB. I will say I use 'clang' to bring it all together. If you have the time try linking through `clang -g` (even though you're using`ld` already) . That would be the only difference. Also, what version LLDB?

Comment: Linking through clang didn't help. `lldb -v` reports "lldb-370.0.42" and "Swift-3.1".